# GitLab: How to open private job artifacts directly via browser

Tags: gitlab, artifact, gitlab-pages

i'm running a pipeline in my GitLab project where automated ui tests are executed. After the tests has been finished it will generate a test report where also a .html file is generated to be able to view the test results in the browser. The generated files will be archived as artifact via the pipeline job.

***.gitlab-ci.yml***

```
artifacts:
    name: ${TESTREPORT_TITLE}
    when: always
    paths:
        - ${ARTIFACT_REPORT}
    reports:
        junit: ${ARTIFACT_REPORT}${TESTREPORT_TITLE}.html.junit.xml
    expire_in: 60 days
```

We have activated GitLab Pages to directly open .html files out of the artifact job archive. That only works for public projects. But in private project it give me following hint:

> The source could not be displayed because it is stored as a job artifact. You can download it instead.

Is there some extra configuration missing?

Our GitLab Instance is self-hosted / On-Premise.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0):

issue is already resolved by making some changes based on the documentation:

To open up (.html) artifacts in private projects:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/index.html#access-control

To enforce mechanics of access control and disable public access of artifacts:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/index.html#disable-public-access-to-all-pages-sites

To set up the access rights to your own needs (i.e. if you want to serve .html artifacts of private projects to the public)

- Go to your Project -> Settings -> General -> See in the section "Pages" under "Visibility, project features, permissions" your settings and adjust there